# "SQL0404: request value for TYPE is too long." error when using parameters

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, parameters

I have a query error with this parameter command. It seems that .NET in the parameter adds extra characters like `vbCrlf. If I try without parameter the update works.

Code:

```
Dim con As OleDbConnection
Dim txt_tip As String

txt_tip = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString(0)
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=172.xx.xx.xx;User Id=user;Password=pwd;"

con = New OleDbConnection(conn.ConnectionString)
con.Open()

Using updCommand As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE $Customers SET TYPE=@type, Name='Rob', Surname='Red', Desc='Test10' WHERE ID=100", con)
updCommand.Parameters.Add("@type", OleDbType.VarChar, 1).Value = txt_tip
updCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

If I try it without the parameters the query works fine:

```
"UPDATE $Customers SET TYPE='1', Name='Rob', Surname='Red', Desc='Test10' WHERE ID=100"
```

The server is IBM AS400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>OP posted answer in comments</sup>

Instead of of specifying a name for the parameter use a `?` as a placeholder:

```
Using updCommand As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE $Customers SET TYPE=?, Name='Rob', Surname='Red', Desc='Test10' WHERE ID=100", con)
    updCommand.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Char).Value = txt_tip
    ...
End Using
```

If you want to add more just ensure the order is correct:

```
Using updCommand As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE $Customers SET TYPE=?, Name=?, Surname=?, Desc='Test10' WHERE ID=100", con)
    updCommand.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Char).Value = txt_tip
    updCommand.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "Rob"
    updCommand.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "Red"
    ...
End Using
```